# Can I apply for a different US visa from within the US? I need to apply for a Schengen visa from NYC

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, indian-citizens

My US student visa expires on June 11 (I have OPT authorization to remain in the country until July end). I have to do a program in Germany from June 24 to August 1, after which I will be returning to my home country, India. (I have an Indian passport).

To apply for a Schengen visa from the US it says my visa has to be valid for 3 months after I leave *from* Germany. Which it's not. But since I'm not returning to the U.S. again, does it matter? How can I get that approved?

Also, if I *did* want to return to the US immediately after my German trip, is it possible to get a US tourist visa while I'm still here, so I could re-enter? Or could I apply for it in Germany?

Comment: The Schengen three month requirement you mention (where your US visa has to be valid for three months after you plan to leave the Schengen zone) is not actually a part of the Schengen visa policy document, but is imposed by consular authorities for administrative convenience. If you explain your situation to them, they can waive that requirement off, based on your circumstances. I've had this waived off for me in a few cases in the past.

Comment: In general, no, you cannot apply for a US visa inside the US. There is an exception for diplomats posted to the US, but that won't help you. Whatever your solution is going to be, it won't be getting a new visa while you're in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all countries have a policy from where you can apply Visa for:

- You can apply from the country, you are a citizen of.
- You can apply from the country, where you have permanent or temporary resident status. This includes Work Visa, Student Visa or Residency Permit. Most countries prohibit applications for Visa in countries where you stay on a tourist visa.
- If the listed countries do not have an embassy or consulate, they generally allow you to apply anywhere.

In the case described, the holder of valid student visa in the US should be eligible for Germany Schengen Visa application in the US.

In the case when you are not planning to return back to the country of residency things may get tricker. You should always explain the situation in the application, and tell that you are planning to go back to the third country after the stay. The main concern for the embassy that you have the right to go back for at least one country. So, there won't be any reason for you to remain in the country as you have no place to go.

Finally, If you have a non-standard situation and you have doubts, you should call or write the embassy or consulate before application.